# Creating a store in the Commerce module fails

Tags: commerce, installation

Using Drupal 9, latest release of Commerce 8.x-2.28. I followed the Lugwig install instructions for the Commerce module. Everything seemed to install OK.

When I fill out the Create Store form, I get an error. The log shows:
Location    http://d9.susansmithjones.com/store/add/online
Referrer    http://d9.susansmithjones.com/store/add/online

Message     Error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection' not found in CommerceGuys\Addressing\Subdivision\Subdivision->__construct() (line 117 of /home/dsusansm/public_html/modules/address/lib/commerceguys-addressing/v1.0.9/src/Subdivision/Subdivision.php)

To review, the Commerce menu is showing and allows me to access the form to create a store. But when I try saving, I get the above message. It seems somehow related to addresses? What have I forgotten to do before creating the store? -->

Comment: `Lugwig install instructions` never heard of it. I suggest you install commerce using Composer instead, which is the preferred way.

Comment: Yeah, Ludwig just isn't going to cut it for Commerce 2.x.

Comment: I used Ludwig because I tried to use composer and it failed. There is a whole doc page on installing Commerce with Ludwig. Perhaps I will go back and try composer again. This is very frustrating.

Comment: Composer is the standard/the best way to go, but there certainly  is  a reason/demand for what Ludwig offert since there is more than 10k sites that use it.

Answer (score 0):

That issue is resolved with the latest dev version of Address, see https://www.drupal.org/project/address/issues/3126733